Whye does Python ctypes GetClassInfoW return corrupt class name?
GetClassInfoW accessed via ctypes on Python 3.12.5 returns a corrupt class name:
    wndclassa = WNDCLASSA()
    user32.GetClassInfoA(hInstance, b'BarClass', wndclassa)
    print(wndclassa.lpszMenuName)
    print(wndclassa.lpszClassName)
    
    wndclassw = WNDCLASSW()
    user32.GetClassInfoW(hInstance, 'BarClass', wndclassw)
    print(wndclassw.lpszMenuName)
    print(wndclassw.lpszClassName)

In the output below, the 4th line is expected to read BarClass. The junk value differs between runs:
b'Foo'
b'BarClass'
Foo
⣰᭺ɒ

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a genuine ctypes bug?
Complete reproducer:
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes as w

def errcheck(result,func,args):
    if result is None or result == 0:
        raise WinError(get_last_error())
    return result

WNDPROC = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int64,w.HWND,w.UINT,w.WPARAM,w.LPARAM)

def WNDCLASS(strtype):
    class WNDCLASS(Structure):
        _fields_ = [('style', w.UINT),
                    ('lpfnWndProc', WNDPROC),
                    ('cbClsExtra', c_int),
                    ('cbWndExtra', c_int),
                    ('hInstance', w.HINSTANCE),
                    ('hIcon', w.HICON),
                    ('hCursor', w.HANDLE),
                    ('hbrBackground', w.HBRUSH),
                    ('lpszMenuName', strtype),
                    ('lpszClassName', strtype)]
    return WNDCLASS

kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32',use_last_error=True)
user32 = WinDLL('user32',use_last_error=True)

kernel32.GetModuleHandleA.argtypes = w.LPCSTR,
kernel32.GetModuleHandleA.restype = w.HMODULE
kernel32.GetModuleHandleA.errcheck = errcheck
hInstance = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(None)

WNDCLASSA = WNDCLASS(w.LPCSTR)
WNDCLASSW = WNDCLASS(w.LPCWSTR)

user32.RegisterClassA.argtypes = POINTER(WNDCLASSA),
user32.RegisterClassA.restype = w.ATOM
user32.RegisterClassA.errcheck = errcheck
user32.GetClassInfoA.argtypes = w.HINSTANCE, w.LPCSTR, POINTER(WNDCLASSA)
user32.GetClassInfoA.restype = w.BOOL
user32.GetClassInfoA.errcheck = errcheck
user32.GetClassInfoW.argtypes = w.HINSTANCE, w.LPCWSTR, POINTER(WNDCLASSW)
user32.GetClassInfoW.restype = w.BOOL
user32.GetClassInfoW.errcheck = errcheck

wndclass = WNDCLASSA()
wndclass.lpfnWndProc    = WNDPROC(user32.DefWindowProcA)
wndclass.hInstance      = hInstance
wndclass.lpszMenuName   = b'Foo'
wndclass.lpszClassName  = b'BarClass'

user32.RegisterClassA(byref(wndclass))

wndclassa = WNDCLASSA()
user32.GetClassInfoA(hInstance, b'BarClass', wndclassa)
print(wndclassa.lpszMenuName)
print(wndclassa.lpszClassName)

wndclassw = WNDCLASSW()
user32.GetClassInfoW(hInstance, 'BarClass', wndclassw)
print(wndclassw.lpszMenuName)
print(wndclassw.lpszClassName)


Do you get the same results in a straight C application?  I've been playing with the code but it seems like a bug.  Foo prints correctly.

A C application works fine, as I'd have expected. I've reported an issue: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/123360

Bug is in your code (it's also in the code that appears to work). In the WNDCLASSW structure, lpszMenuName can be a resource name or numeric ID. Similarly, lpszClassName could be a class name or its atom. You'll have to use the equivalent of ISINTRESOURCE() to determine which one it is. You cannot just assume that they point to character strings.

@IInspectable It is returning a valid pointer, but the pointer isn't an atom.  The pointer points to what looks like a uint64 value (0x1).  If that is an atom shouldn't GetAtomName(1) return BarClass?  It happens to return '#1'.

@MarkTolonen The "string" types are either pointers or numeric values. Never are they pointers to atoms/resource IDs. "#1" is the third representation: It's the numeric resource ID or atom represented as a string.

@IInspectable Well, it is a pointer that isn't an atom then.  An atom is a ushort value.  The pointer points to memory that contains 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00, which isn't the lpszClassName that was registered.  It doesn't make sense.  If you have an working example I'd like to see it.

@MarkTolonen I'm just spelling out the rules. I cannot explain the observed behavior nor test the code. Beyond the problems addressed above, there's another issue with the code: No error handling. For all we know GetClassInfoW could fail. After all, no (Unicode) window class was registered with the wide-character name BarClass. I don't know what 'BarClass' evaluates to in Python. The API expects a UTF-16LE-encoded, zero-terminated character string.

@IInspectable In my attempt to reproduce and fix I was error checking. And ctypes marshals str to UTF-16LE encoding. It does appear to be reporting garbage for that value.

@MarkTolonen Have you verified what corresponding C code would report? This could be a bug in the OS after all. Or just the fallout from using the API out-of-specification.

I wrote some equivalent C code, and that one works as expected. In the code form question all functions succeed (otherwise an exception would be raised). I have a modified version of Python code, and apparently when I run it with Python 032bit, I can see rClass  after 4 messed up bytes.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica: You should probably add a (short) answer to the question and mark it as a solution.
